# Openlayers H3 Binning works but map only displays on page load

Tags: openlayers, javascript, openlayers-2, h3

I focused on an example of H3-JS binning work on Mapbox map canvas.
https://gis.utah.gov/developer/applications/suitability/

However, I wanted to work with Openlayers map. With some help I was able to make H3-JS work with Openlayers.

Here is the working code: https://jsbin.com/nosoyonemi/edit?html,output

[image]

Now I would only like to load that map when a button is clicked, not on page load.
So I added a button and called the map load.

Code here: https://jsbin.com/waqojixipo/1/edit?html,output

I made the map display to none

```
<div id="mapContainer" style="display: none;"></div>
```

and added the following code

```
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="Show Map" onclick="displayMap();" />

function displayMap(){
       var x = document.getElementById("mapContainer");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

**But on the button click, no map is displayed**

Even if I change the following code, to make the map not visible upon load

```
const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    **"visible":false,** //added to make it visible
```

and then make it visible later on in the code

```
for (let input of inputs) {
  input.addEventListener("change", () => {
    console.log("event listener")
    //refreshMap2(vectorLayer); //wasnt showing so lets call another function
    **vectorLayer.setVisible(true)**; 
  });
}
```

It still is not visible upon button click. **Though The map zoom option does display.**

**I was hoping someone could tell me how to display the map - not on page load, but on button click.**

Please feel free to modify the JSBIN code: https://jsbin.com/waqojixipo/1/edit?html,output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you make changes to the map div visibility or size you must call `map.updateSize()`.

In your case you must declare `map` before defining the `displayMap` function:

```
  <script>
    let map;
    function displayMap(){
      var x = document.getElementById("mapContainer");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
        map.updateSize();
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>
```

so further down in your code `const map =` should be changed to `map =`.

Comment: Mike, the answer works. Its just that moving the binning sliders does not show the binning. Please see my changes here: https://jsbin.com/jomobicosa/edit?html,output

Comment: Also, while the map shows, there is still an error in the comsole view
"ReferenceError: map is not defined

Comment: Hi @Mike -  the OL-map conflicts with my another OL-map I have on the same page. I posted it as a question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/444162/two-openlayers-maps-with-different-versions-only-either-shows. Would it be possible to create a OL hexabinning solution that works for the previous OL version?