# Two Openlayers maps with different versions, only either shows

Tags: openlayers, javascript, css

I have 2 openlayers maps on the same web page. Only one of them shows as importing the css and js libraries related to each map, makes the other one not visible.

I have tried commenting the ol.js and ol.css required for each map, but I have to comment the other. **Is there a way I can show both maps on the same page?**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ol.css" /> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/gifplayer.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/turf.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/shpwrite.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="assets/js/ol.js"></script> -->
<script src="assets/js/shp.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/FileSaver.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/xyz.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.gifplayer.js"></script>
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@main/dist/en/v7.1.0/ol/ol.css" /> 

<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-fetch@2.0.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@main/dist/en/v7.1.0/ol/dist/ol.js"></script> 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/h3-js@3.7.0"></script>
```

I cannot use the second set of ol.js and .css only, as it does not contain one of the functions needed for the first map to show - Please see the error.

I have uploaded the code at https://github.com/sharmapn/testOL
You may need to put on a webserver to run - to prevent the cors error. Code is in the index.html file.

Use Firefox, Click 'Show Map', and press F12 to show map.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Added html code.

Comment: There is no alternative to answer from @smomapz.

Answer (score 1):

The two OL versions are conflicting.

You have these options for example:

- migrate either OL-map to the same OL-version of the other one
- run either OL-map in an iFrame displaying a separable JS-scope

Comment: I was wondering if the conflict is within the css or js. Would there be any resources on how to migrate - I couldn't find any resources.